# Anylogic find agent in population and access one of its variables

Tags: anylogic, agent

I want to find the index my agent has in its population (named dullieses), which lives in my Main-agent.
I want to find one of my dullieses-agent via one of its variables (DullyID) which, in this example, shall be equal to my counter variable. Both are of type int.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
int i = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < dullieses.size(); i++){
    if (Main.dullieses(i).DullyID == counter){
        traceln("I found myself! I have the index " + i);
    break;
    }
}
```

Error code: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dullies(int) from type Main.

How can I find my agent in my population and find its index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably already in main and don't need to add `Main.`.
Anyway, I would recommend using:

```
Dully d = findFirst( dullieses, d -> d.ID == counter );
d.variable = 10;
```

I used variable and 10 as random examples, but this should give you the idea. Also replace `Dully` with whatever your agent type name is.

Comment: I get the error code: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Main.dullieses"

Comment: Is it in main? Are you writing the code from within main?

Comment: If I try with a filter, as in "filter(dullieses, d -> d.ID == counter);" it tells me that "ID cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Is it ID or DullyID ?

Comment: Its DullyID, sorry! But how do I access the agents in my filter now to change its variable?

Comment: Check revised answer

Comment: That works! I have this code in the "enter"-section of a delay-block and if another agent enters the delay-block I get a nullpointer exception. But in my population there are still other agents...

Comment: Probably none of the agents in the population match your condition.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a custom ID parameter in your agents (at least not for what you're doing here).

All agents in a population have the `getIndex` function which returns their index in the population. Just be wary that, if you remove agents from a population, their indices will change (so you can't, for example, use their index as a unique ID for them in that case).